# Ubuntu Server performance boost

Tags: server, performance, boost

Is there any way to boost an Ubuntu Server's performance? I feel it a bit laggy when hosting a game server on it, unlike other servers. Do you think installing a desktop environment will decrease the server's performance?

Currently I only have an FTP service installed, nothing else. (I use SSH to connect to it.)

VM specs:
⠀OS: Ubuntu Server 14.04
⠀CPU: Dual Core 2.13GHz (2 processors)
⠀RAM: 4GB
⠀Disk: 40GB

Answer (score 0):

It could be a variety of things. You should edit your question to include more detail specs of the host machine, state what virtualization product you are using, and if the product uses guest drivers state whether you've installed them. The information below may or may not apply to you depending on what product you are using to host the virtual machine.

- Depending on how much ram your host has, and what kinds of ram usage the host and guest operating system are under it's possible your VM is getting swapped memory from the host. The virtual machine gives 4gb of memory from the host. However if not enough ram is available on the host that memory could be coming from your swap partition instead which would dramatically decrease performance in the virtual machine. If you have enough ram try disabling your host's swap partition and seeing if the vm's performance increases.
- Another thing to consider where the vm is stored. For optimal performance it should be placed on it's own storage device, that has a fast connection interface, and good read/write speeds.
- If the virtual machine product you are using has guest drivers installing them will aid performance.
- If you have more than 2 cpus available on the host then assigning more may help depending on what virtualization product you are using. For example when I record high quality audio in virtual machines I dedicate all 4 of my cpus to prevent skipping.

Comment: Not helpful.

On the same machine I had a Windows Server installed and I feel it a bit laggy after switching to Ubuntu Server unlike my previous condition. That means the machine is working correctly I just need a way to make the OS more light-weight and give higher priority to the game-server :)